# How to fix this infinite loop? (AP Computer Science)

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a digit: ");
        int digit = in.nextInt();

        boolean isAnInteger = false;
        while (isAnInteger)
        {
            if (digit >= 10)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Correct! " + digit + " is an integer!");
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm currently taking AP Computer Science and I'm curious as to how to solve this (albeit basic) issue. I'm aware that "while" loops continue whatever is in their respective curly brackets when a condition in their parenthesis continues to be a met.

When I tried setting the `while` condition to `while (digit >= 10)`, it resulted in an infinite loop (correct me, but it is due to the fact that if the user inputs a digit of 10 or greater, the condition will KEEP being met and continue infinitely). So, I tried setting the while condition to some boolean value, and an `if` nested inside with the prior condition. Now, when the user enters 10, nothing happens after, and the program ends.

How do I write the above code so that the System will continue printing "Please enter an integer:" if the condition (of inputting 10 or greater and the opposite) continues to be met?

Comment: Why don't you update `isAnInteger` anywhere in your loop?

Comment: @Makoto has it right. As it is right now though, your loop should never execute at all (let alone infinitely) since `isAnInteger` is set to `false`.

Comment: should "integer" be "digit" in this statement?: `System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");` and same in the other System.println(...)?

Comment: whole numbers greater than 10 are still integers

Comment: As you are starting to learn computer science, you should learn good practices from the start. One of those good practices is choosing appropriate variable names. You have "while (digit >= 10)". Obviously if 'digit' was really a digit, it could never be >= 10 because it would then be two or more digits.

Comment: most of the answers are ignoring what may be a subtle requirement:  from your description of the condition "of inputting 10 or greater and the opposite", you are probably supposed to be repeating the loop until a value between -9 and 9 is input, not just a number between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a basic "poor design" issue that the variable `isAnInteger` has a scope wider than needed (it lives past the last line that needs it).

The "correct" approach is loop that contains the logic that determines "integerness" of the input and doesn't leave variables in scope when the loop ends, other than the captured input in `digit` of course.

Next, you want to separate the concerns of capturing input with checking it, so first create a method that gets a digit:

```
private static int readNumber(Scanner in) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a digit: ");
    int digit = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine(); // you must clear the newline char from the buffer
    return digit;
}
```

Next, write a simple `while()` loop that keeps reading until it gets good input:

```
int digit = 10; // bad input
while (digit > 9) {
    digit = readNumber(in);
}
```

Putting it all together with the final message:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int digit = 10; // initialize with "bad" input
    while (digit > 9) {
         digit = readNumber(in);
    }
    System.out.println("Correct! " + digit + " is an integer!");
}

private static int readNumber(Scanner in) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a digit: ");
    int digit = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine(); // you must clear the newline char from the buffer
    return digit;
}
```

This approach makes the code much easier to read and understand.
Also notice how there is no repeated code (such as the line asking for a digit, or reading input).

Comment: `in.next(); // you must clear the newline char from the buffer` ... `next` won't do that.

Comment: This behaviour isn't related to the used delimiter. Both, the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) and a [simple test](http://pastebin.com/pKbgJ9hD)(#) show that `next` won't consume the delimiter if this is the only thing to read from the source. (#) You can either paste the whole input at once, then you get an empty line from `nextLine` or you can write it manually, then you will see that `next` blocks the thread until it gets a token.

Comment: @Tom You are quite correct. Now I know the difference when using the default delimiter (excuse: I rarely use scanner)

Comment: I would say that there is always a difference: 'next' requires a valid token before it returns, whereas 'nextLine' reads everything until the next delimiter and doesn't care if it was a "valid" token or not. That is why it has problems if the stream contains data like `[delimiter]more data[delimter]`. 'nextLine' would first return an empty String, whereas 'next' would return the data token. Methods like 'nextInt' or 'nextFloat' also skip delimiters until it could read a valid token (and may throw an Exception if the "type" of the token was incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

The main conceptual piece here is that you don't update your value anywhere inside of your loop.  Because it does not update, it will always remain the value it was when it entered the loop (that is, `digit >= 10` will remain true until the program stops running).

You must update your values inside of your loop.

However, there's another concept you're missing:  you're guaranteed to run the loop at least once, so you should take advantage of the `do...while` loop instead.

Note that I make use of `nextLine()` to avoid any wonky `nextInt()` issues.

(Oh, by the way:  any number you're looking for *is* an integer. You should communicate that you're looking for an integer less than 10 instead.)

```
System.out.print("Please enter a digit: ");
int digit = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

boolean isAnInteger;

do {
    if (digit >= 10) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
        digit = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        isAnInteger = false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Correct! " + digit + " is an integer!");
        isAnInteger = true;
    }
} while (isAnInteger);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Makoto has it right.

You never update your values inside the `while` loop. In your original case, when you just wanted to keep printing out `Please enter an integer:` , you never ask for an input right after that line. Your original `digit` value will continue to be greater than or equal to 10, and will keep the loop going.

Even with your current code, you will still run into an infinite loop if your `digit` value is less than 10. Notice how the boolean `isAnInteger` is independent of whether your `digit` is less than 10.

The best way to fix this is by using something like this:

```
    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter a digit: ");
    int digit = in.nextInt();

    while (digit >= 10)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
        digit = in.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Correct! " + digit + " is an integer!");
```

What this does is it keeps checking to see if digit is greater than or equal to 10. If so, it will continue to ask the user for an input. If at any time during the iteration of the loop the user enters a value less than 10, it will not execute the next iteration, and leaves the loop. It will then execute the last `println`.

However, if the first input is less than 10, it will skip the while loop and execute the `println` at the bottom.

If you want to use a boolean like you did, you can do it in such a manner:

```
    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter a digit: ");
    int digit = in.nextInt();

    bool isAnInteger = true;
    if (digit >= 10)
        isAnInteger = false;

    while (!isAnInteger)  // checks if digit is not an integer
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
        digit = in.nextInt();

        if !(digit >= 10)
            isAnInteger = true;
    }
    System.out.println("Correct! " + digit + " is an integer!");
```

Makoto's way of using a `do while` loop is probably better, although this may be a better way of visualizing it (since you used a `while` loop).